# PostGIS with SFCGAL support from source

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.3

I would like to install SFCGAL support in Postgis so I tried to install it from source.

Ubuntu 13.04, PostgreSQL was installed from package.

PostGIS is now configured for i686-pc-linux-gnu

```
 -------------- Compiler Info -------------
  C compiler:           gcc -g -O2
  C++ compiler:         g++ -g -O2
  SQL preprocessor:     /usr/bin/cpp -w -traditional-cpp -P

 -------------- Dependencies --------------
  GEOS config:          /etc/geos-3.4.2/tools/geos-config
  GEOS version:         3.4.2
  GDAL config:          /usr/local/bin/gdal-config
  GDAL version:         1.10.1
  SFCGAL config:        /usr/include/SFCGAL
  SFCGAL version:
  PostgreSQL config:    /usr/bin/pg_config
  PostgreSQL version:   PostgreSQL 9.3.2
  PROJ4 version:        48
  Libxml2 config:       /usr/bin/xml2-config
  Libxml2 version:      2.9.0
  JSON-C support:       yes
  PostGIS debug level:  0
  Perl:                 /usr/bin/perl

 --------------- Extensions ---------------
  PostGIS Raster:       enabled
  PostGIS Topology:     enabled
  SFCGAL support:       enabled

 -------- Documentation Generation --------
  xsltproc:
  xsl style sheets:
  dblatex:
  convert:
  mathml2.dtd:          http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/mathml2.dtd
```

I always got this error If I install it --without-raster or --with-raster:

```
./configure --with-raster --with-topology --with-geosconfig=/etc/geos-3.4.2/tools/geos-config --with-sfcgal=/usr/include/SFCGAL --with-projdir=/etc/proj-4.8.0

../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_point_x'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_geometry_collection_num_geometries'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_polygon_add_interior_ring'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_geometry_collection_create'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_version'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_polygon_exterior_ring'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_geometry_is_3d'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_solid_create_from_exterior_shell'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_point_create_from_xy'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_triangle_create'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_point_create_from_xyz'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_geometry_type_id'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_linestring_create'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_triangle_vertex'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_linestring_point_n'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_geometry_collection_add_geometry'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_geometry_collection_geometry_n'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_geometry_delete'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_multi_linestring_create'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_triangle_set_vertex_from_xy'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_multi_polygon_create'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_polygon_interior_ring_n'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_triangulated_surface_create'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_polygon_num_interior_rings'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_multi_point_create'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_solid_shell_n'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_polyhedral_surface_num_polygons'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_triangulated_surface_triangle_n'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_point_create'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_point_z'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_polygon_create_from_exterior_ring'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_geometry_is_empty'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_triangulated_surface_add_triangle'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_polyhedral_surface_create'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_triangle_set_vertex_from_xyz'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_linestring_num_points'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_polyhedral_surface_polygon_n'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_solid_num_shells'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_triangulated_surface_num_triangles'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_polyhedral_surface_add_polygon'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_point_y'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_linestring_add_point'
../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.so: undefined reference to `sfcgal_polygon_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [raster2pgsql] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/etc/postgis-2.1.2/raster/loader'
make[1]: *** [rtloader] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/etc/postgis-2.1.2/raster'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: What did your `./configure` command look like? I don't see `sfcgal-config` anywhere.

Comment: `./configure --with-raster --with-topology --with-geosconfig=/etc/geos-3.4.2/tools/geos-config --with-sfcgal=/usr/include/SFCGAL --with-projdir=/etc/proj-4.8.0` @Mike T

Comment: Balazs did you solve it? I'm faceng the same problem